# Как сделать отслеживание выделения текста на странице?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Есть скрипт для Google Tag Manager, который отслеживает копирования текста на странице. Возможно ли его изменить так, чтобы отслеживалось просто выделение текста, без копирования? Т.е. пользователь выделил текст на странице — отправилось событие в Google Tag Manager.

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e)
{
    var selected_text = window.getSelection().toString().replace("\n", ' ');
    var l = selected_text.length;
    if(l > 50)
    {
        selected_text = selected_text.substring(0, 20) + ' ... ' +
                        selected_text.substring(l - 20, l);
    }
    dataLayer.push({'selected_text':selected_text,'event':'copy'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, возможно. Просто замените событие `oncopy` на `onselect`. Вот так:

```
document.addEventListener('select', function(e)
{
    var selected_text = window.getSelection().toString().replace("\n", ' ');
    var l = selected_text.length;
    if(l > 50)
    {
        selected_text = selected_text.substring(0, 20) + ' ... ' +
                        selected_text.substring(l - 20, l);
    }
    dataLayer.push({'selected_text':selected_text,'event':'copy'});
});
```